# db.fsyncLock() and db.fsyncUnlock() in MongoDB Database(Auth enabled) get it blocked

Tags: mongodb, authentication, fsync, database

I have performed a

1. **db.fsyncLock()**
2. BackUp orders
3. **db.fsyncUnlock()**

Later, I try to do some common operations in the database,like find() but **it is blocked** and **doesn´t return anything**.
I have to do a restart of the mongodb to make it work again.

What I am  doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in the log files?

Comment: where i can see the logs?

Comment: The log location is specified with the --logpath command line option or systemLog.path config file option when you start mongod. If you don't set either, it logs to the terminal window by default. You can check the command line options from the mongo shell by running db.runCommand({getCmdLineOpts : 1}) against the admin database.

Comment: Ok,anyway i think this is a common error.Auth mongobs that performs a lock later cannot be unlocked.You know something about this problem/bug?

Comment: We need to see some more information, like what's the logs, before we can give a better determination about what's going on.